# How can I access the position of an object in the array (json) and change its values by php

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have to access the array and change the data of the member chosen to modify and overwrite the old ones, I have tried several times but does nothing but add it instead of removing it.

I tried passing the position of the element through its index but it doesn't replace it. Even looking through its unique id.

The first element had to overwrite the second one instead created a new one at the beginning of the array.
json

```
[
    {
        "surname": "",
        "name": "Andrea Fiore",
        "city": "Crocino",
        "address": "via Emo Mannucci, 2",
        "telephone": "123456789",
        "email": "x@gmail.com",
        "startData": "2019-07-04",
        "finishData": "2019-07-25",
        "cardId": "2",
        "state": "true"
    },
    {
        "surname": "Fioregg",
        "name": "Andrea Fiore",
        "city": "Crocino",
        "address": "via Emo Mannucci, 2",
        "telephone": "123456789",
        "email": "x@gmail.com",
        "startData": "2019-07-04",
        "finishData": "2019-07-25",
        "cardId": "2",
        "state": "true"
    }
]
```

The last code I used to try to modify the member.
php

```
<?php

   $getOldData = "data.php";
   $elaborateNewMember = array();
  try
  {
       $contenentData = file_get_contents($getOldData);

       $elaborateNewMember = json_decode($contenentData, true);
       $find = array_filter($elaborateNewMember, function($searchMember) {
           return $searchMember['cardId'] == $_POST['cardId'];
       });
       if(count(($indexs = array_keys($find))) == 1) {
           $elaborateNewMember[indexs[0]] = array(
            'surname'=> $_POST['surname'],
            'name'=> $_POST['name'],
            'city'=> $_POST['city'],
            'address'=> $_POST['address'],
            'telephone'=> $_POST['telephone'],
            'email'=> $_POST['email'],
            'startData'=> $_POST['startData'],
            'finishData'=> $_POST['finishData'],
            'cardId'=> $_POST['cardId'],
            'state'=> $_POST['state'],
           );
       $contenentData = json_encode($elaborateNewMember, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
       
       if(file_put_contents($getOldData, $contenentData)) {
            echo 'Aggiornamento riuscito.';
        }
       else 
            echo "Errore.";

   }
  }
   catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Eccezione: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }

?>
```

I tried this but after in the json file it add the member to change in new object with index 'i'.

Comment: `array_push` adds new element at the end of array. If you want to replace something in array, use this construction `$arr[$index] = $data`

Comment: I have already tried this, but did not replace it but always created a new one.

Comment: Here you can see my solution https://3v4l.org/AklO9

Comment: `$contentDataArray[0] = $newMemberData;` - you're assuming this element is always at index point 0, this isn't dynamic @potiev

Comment: It is as example, you can use any unique id

Comment: Thus it isn't a solution then @potiev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to preserve the array keys.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.php'), true);    

$filter = array_filter($data, function($row) {
    return $row['email'] == $_POST['email']; // Assuming this is unique
});
```

If a match was returned, and only one, you can update that index in your data.

```
if(count(($indexs = array_keys($filter))) == 1) {
    $data[$indexs[0]] = array(
        'surname'=> $_POST['surname'],
        'name'=> $_POST['name'],
        'city'=> $_POST['city'],
        'address'=> $_POST['address'],
        'telephone'=> $_POST['telephone'],
        'email'=> $_POST['email'],
        'startData'=> $_POST['startData'],
        'finishData'=> $_POST['finishData'],
        'cardId'=> $_POST['cardId'],
        'state'=> $_POST['state'],
    );
}
```

Then just re-write the file. See a [working demo here](https://3v4l.org/nJHgO)

If you have multiple emails for that user you want to update the arrays for, you can loop through the indexs.

```
if(count(($indexs = array_keys($filter))) >= 1)
    foreach($indexs as $key)
        $data[$key] = array(
            'surname'=> $_POST['surname'],
            'name'=> $_POST['name'],
            'city'=> $_POST['city'],
            'address'=> $_POST['address'],
            'telephone'=> $_POST['telephone'],
            'email'=> $_POST['email'],
            'startData'=> $_POST['startData'],
            'finishData'=> $_POST['finishData'],
            'cardId'=> $_POST['cardId'],
            'state'=> $_POST['state'],
        );
```

Comment: Now i try this, after I test it and get the answer if this work or not for me. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer to provide full example @AndreaFiore

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem, thanks a lot to @Jaquarh.
Here is the final code I used:
php

```
<?php

   $getOldData = "data.php";
   $elaborateNewMember = array();
  try
  {
       $contenentData = file_get_contents($getOldData);

       $elaborateNewMember = json_decode($contenentData, true);
       $find = array_filter($elaborateNewMember, function($searchMember) {
           return $searchMember['cardId'] == $_POST['cardId'];
       });
       if(count(($indexs = array_keys($find))) == 1) {
           $elaborateNewMember[$indexs[0]] = array(
            'surname'=> $_POST['surname'],
            'name'=> $_POST['name'],
            'city'=> $_POST['city'],
            'address'=> $_POST['address'],
            'telephone'=> $_POST['telephone'],
            'email'=> $_POST['email'],
            'startData'=> $_POST['startData'],
            'finishData'=> $_POST['finishData'],
            'cardId'=> $_POST['cardId'],
            'state'=> $_POST['state'],
            'try'=> $indexs[0],
            'tryxxx'=> $find,
           );
       $contenentData = json_encode($elaborateNewMember, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

       if(file_put_contents($getOldData, $contenentData)) {
            echo 'Aggiornamento riuscito.';
        }
       else 
            echo "Errore.";

   };
  }
   catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Eccezzione: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }

?>
```

Thanks a lot for your help.